# Ionic 4 and Cordova is not available

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have problems with cordova on my android device.
I searched github issues and the web for solutions and nothing worked for me yet.

In my code I have got `this.platform.ready()` and e.g. `this.splashScreen.hide()`. If I build my app (does not matter if production build or not) and cordova build (does not matter if production build or not) and install the apk on my android device, adb logcat logs:

```
03-17 00:58:54.608  8769  8769 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator",
```

Regarding to some guys, the `@ionic/angular-toolkit` does not include the cordova.js in the index.html at build time due to livereloading enabled.

Even downgrading to `ng-toolkit v 1.08` does not work for me (also changed in angular.json).

The only solution which is working is `ionic cordova run android`.

Any suggestions or workarounds to build apks with cordova available without run? I know `ionic cordova run android` is also building an apk but why does this work and a `ng build` + `ionic cordova build android` & `adb install apk` is not working?

Some system info here:

- Ionic 4.12.0
- Ionic Framework 4.1.1
- angular/cli 7.3.6
- angular-toolkit 1.1.0
- cordova 8.1.2
- cordova platforms android 7.1.4
- nodejs 10.15.3
- npm 6.9.0
- cordova-android 8.0.0

Comment: try to remove platform and add it again

Comment: already tried that, does not work.

Comment: LoadUrlTimeoutValue does not exist in my config.xml

Comment: nevermind what do you get if you run `cordova plugin ls`

Comment: I was receiving  same issue like “cordova_not_available” 
uninstall all the plugins
uninstall the platform
re-install the platform
re-install the plugins

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Actually, I had the workaround with the ionic cordova run android. I formatted my computer weeks ago and now its working correctly with ng build + ionic cordova build android. I guess some weird interna configuration shit happened there