# Ionic 4 cordova not available when using admob free

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 4 app with the admob free plugin. This is my code to show my banner:

**admob.service.ts**

```
` BannerAd(admobid) {
    let bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: false, 
      autoShow: true,
      id: admobid
    };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

    this.admobFree.banner.prepare().then(() => {
      // success
    }).catch(e => alert(e));
  }  `
```

On a page I call this method like this:

```
 this.admob.BannerAd(this.id);
```

The **test** ads works fine but when I wanna use the production ads the banner is shown as a black bar under the screen. I get 2 warnings in my google console.

> common.js:290 Native: tried calling AdMobFree.config, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
>
> common.js:290 Native: tried calling AdMobFree.prepare, but Cordova is
>   not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a
>   device/simulator

I have already tried several solutions

**Solution 1**

[Ionic 4 and Cordova is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207144/ionic-4-and-cordova-is-not-available)

**Solution 2**

Migrated to a new fresh project

How can I show the production ads in my Ionic 4 app?

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
    "@ionic-native/admob-free": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.3.0",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "cordova-admob-sdk": "0.24.1",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "0.26.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.14.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^3.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  },
```

Comment: Wait a few days, ads will show up automatically

Comment: Do you know how many days?

Comment: maximum 2-3 days

Comment: I have waited for a few days still have black ads...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the following command after 3 days:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

I uploaded the APK file to the Google playstore for beta testing. When I installed the app on my phone to test. The ads appeared and everything works.